# Infinite repetition (iteration) in Elisp code

Tags: iteration

There is an option to

> repeat a macro an infinite number of times until the function quits (for example, by reaching the end of the buffer) or if the user cancels the command in keyboard macros

by using <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> as prefix to <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>.

How can we mimic this behavior in Elisp code with the loop? For example, I would like to write a code that brings point to the outermost bracket to check if it is of a certain value:

```
(defun outer-paren()
  (interactive)
  (while condition
    (up-list)))
```

What should `condition` be to mimic keyboard macro infinite argument behavior?

> ((some (|text) embedded) within brackets) --> |((some (text) embedded) within brackets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really ask two questions:

1. **How to iterate forever?**

   `(while t ...)`

   See the Elisp manual, node [Iteration](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Iteration.html).

   The first argument of `while` is a sexp. It is evaluated to see if the body needs to be evaluated again. The sexp `t` always evaluates to itself, a non-`nil` value, so the body is always reevaluated.
2. **How to get the outermost list?**

```el
    (defun outer-paren ()
      "Return the outermost list."
      (interactive)
      (let ((xs  nil))
        (while (setq xs  (list-at-point)) (up-list))
        xs))
```

But I recommend using `tap-list-at-point` (or `tap-unquoted-list-at-point`), from library [Thing-At-Point-Plus](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ThingAtPointPlus#Lists), rather than the vanilla `list-at-point`.

Comment: How do I prevent `Scan error: "Unbalanced parentheses", 186, 186` from cropping up when the function is executed?

Comment: Updated, to reflect that second question. (You really should pose only one question per question, however.)